# How to find sql query row size

Tags: sql, db2, size, row

I am running into SQL issue

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1585, SQLSTATE=54048

I already have 32K temp table space. I want to figure out what is the row size of my SQL query, so that I can quickly found out, how much I am going beyond 32K.

Answer (score 4):

From the DB2 Command Line Processor, you can use `describe` for an SQL statement:

```
$ db2 "describe select tabschema,tabname from syscat.tables"

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 2

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 448   VARCHAR                 128  TABSCHEMA                                 9
 448   VARCHAR                 128  TABNAME                                   7
```

You're interested in the *Type length* column.  For the example SQL statement here, it's 256 bytes.

Obviously, use your own query.

`describe` is not a SQL statement, so it's not available to applications connecting via JDBC or ODBC.  I'm not sure if there are metadata methods you can call on a prepared statement to get the equivalent information.